# Android Shared Preferences not displaying

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to create simple app for learning purposes. You enter a text, app saves it using `Shared Preferences`. And in the TextView I want to display this saved text.

My code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
EditText editText;
TextView textSaved;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    textSaved = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.savedtext);
    editText = ( EditText ) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    LoadPreferences();

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SavePreferences("Text1", editText.getText().toString());
            LoadPreferences();
        }
    });
}

protected void SavePreferences(String string, String string2) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(string, string2);
    editor.commit();
}

private void LoadPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String stringSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("Text", "");
    textSaved.setText(stringSaved);
}
```

TextView in xml:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/savedtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But the `shared preferences` text isn't getting showed in `TextView`. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences("Pref_Name",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also the key is different while saving and fetching.

```
String stringSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("Text", "");
```

Use Text1 on both places

Comment: Thank you, changed Text to Text1 in both cases and everything works.

Answer (score 2):

You have saved it to preference `"Text1"`, but are reading from `"Text"`

Change them to match, for example:

```
SavePreferences("Text", editText.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
String stringSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("Text", "");
```

to this:

```
   String stringSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("Text1", "");
```

for more informations you can check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 1):

Replace following line

```
String stringSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("Text", "");
```

with

```
String stringSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("Text1", "");
```

For more about sharedPreferences from [My tutorial](http://androiddevelopmentworld.blogspot.in/2013/04/shared-preferences-in-android.html).